# make a query not in subquery as a condition with enum value

Tags: postgresql

i have a schema called `users`

`user_id`   `state`  `transition`

```
  1.       accept   v1
  1.       refused  v1
  2.       accept   v1
  2.       refused  v2
```

with `no primary key` in the table `users` and a enum values for `state` and `transition`

I have to get a `distinct user_id where transition!='v2'`

the result that i want

`user_id`

```
   1
```

as `user_id=2` has a `transition=v2`

I made this query but is not working or at least giving me duplicate `user_id`

```
select  T.user_id from users T 
                         where  T.user_id not 
          in  
(select 1  from users where transition='v2' and users.ad_id=T.user_id 
                                           group by user_id) limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query must looks like this:

```
select distinct user_id from users where transition != 'v2';
```

With purpose to limit your result just add `limit 10` in the end of the query.

---

With purpose exclude users which appears twice in table with different transition versions - try this:

```
select distinct user_id from users where user_id not in (
  select user_id from users where transition = 'v2'
);
```

Comment: i have aleardy done this query but is not working for my result wanted , for your query is gonna return me the `user_id=2` that i have not be returned as having a `transition=v2` i updated the problem with the result wanted to be more clear thanks for your collaboration

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir Kovpak it's working but the runtime query is slow due to the huge data handling with   is there a another way to optimize this query or it is the only for my case ??

Comment: @dev_medo It's possible to speed it up: 1) rewrite query to use join (join table users with v1 and table users with v2 and exclude users with v2 - but this pretty complicated query) 2) alter table and add indexes.

Comment: with using a twin join ( copy of the same table) we will gain in term of scalability?